# mysql show variables like 'innodb%' returned nothing

Tags: mysql

I am running a MySQL server 5.1.61 on a RHEL6.3. The MysQL server runs OK but I found that I need to tune the innodb_buffer_pool_size. I thought that this variable can be displayed using

> mysql> show variables like 'innodb%';

but actually, it returns nothing. Why does it return nothing? Where can I see the actual innodb_buffer_pool_size (besides my.cnf file).

PS: I understand that I can change the innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.cnf and restart the MySQL, but why cannot I see its actual value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On MySQL 5.1, it's possible for the InnoDB storage engine to fail to initialize, if it encounters an error during startup.  In that case, it just disables InnoDB and carries on.  MyISAM tables will be accessible, but no InnoDB tables will.

Check that the InnoDB storage engine is enabled.  Here's the output from an instance of 5.1.65:

```
mysql> show variables like 'have_innodb';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_innodb   | YES   |
+---------------+-------+

mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
. . .
```

Next I simulated an InnoDB failure, by editing my.cnf to set `innodb_log_file_size=256M`, which is not the size of the log files on disk.  Then I restarted the instance.

```
mysql> show variables like 'have_innodb';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_innodb   | NO    |
+---------------+-------+

mysql> show variables like 'innodb%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Trouble!  Where to look?  The error log file:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes!
130218 12:50:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130218 12:50:46 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

You can also force MySQL to abort its startup if it encounters an error initializing InnoDB, so you never get into this situation again.  Add this to /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
innodb=force
```

Then when I try to start up, I see this in the error log:

```
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 5242880 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 268435456 bytes!
130218 12:55:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
130218 12:55:03 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
130218 12:55:03 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
130218 12:55:03 [ERROR] Aborting

130218 12:55:03 [Note] /home/billkarwin/opt/mysql/5.1.65/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

In MySQL 5.5, the server will not start up if InnoDB fails to initialize.

Comment: Thank you for resolving this issue! I think you are right, but the question is how to fix this ib_logfile0 issue?

Comment: If the log file size is the cause of the error, try changing the my.cnf to have the file size as it exists on disk.  Then restart the mysql service.

Comment: I mark your answer as correct. I am sorry but I took action before seeing your answer. What I did was to move (not delete) the ib_log files and then restart MySQL server. This time, the innodb starts but there are some error message as below: "Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 20. The table is probably corrupted. 130218 21:25:03 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 29". I guess my action causes some tables to be corrupted. Is there any easy fix? If not, I may need to re-install the MySQL server and re-import the data. What do you think, Bill? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you just upgraded from 5.0.x to 5.1.x (or later) and you didn't run `mysql_upgrade` to add new columns to the system tables.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Answer (score 2):

Try `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name LIKE 'innodb%'`